# What is the Task version of Async.Sequential in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, f#-async

The below code used to work - but I am converting a lot of my async{} functions to task{} and I can't figure out how to make it run sequentially without a mutable variable.

```
let processBatchTransaction(page: IPage, 
                            bnzBatch: BNZBatch, 
                            cardTransactionswithOrder: BNZCardWithOrder list,
                            xeroClient: XeroClientFull) : Task<StatusMessage> = task {
    let matchedTransactionsSeq 
        = seq{
                for cardTransactionWithOrder in cardTransactionswithOrder do
                    let matchedTransaction = matchTransaction(page,bnzBatch,cardTransactionWithOrder, xeroClient)
                    yield matchedTransaction
        }

    let! matchedTransactions = matchedTransactionsSeq |> Async.Sequential
.... etc
}
```

The function "matchTransaction" used to be async - but there is no Task.Sequential, only Task.WhenAll but I need them to run synchronously one after the other.

Comment: You might use `taskSeq`, but it’s still in prototype state (see F# compiler tests on GitHub). A better alternative may be F#+. Just a few days ago, `SeqT` was added to support just this scenario. You can also write it by hand with `Task.ContinueWith`. The reason this is not supported is that tasks are hot started. The moment you create them, they start (same in C#). (I may write up a full answer tomorrow, it’s a bit late here)

Comment: You can also use [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) generic `sequence` function in lieu of `Async.Sequential`. It will work with either Asyncs or Tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: see all the way below for a simpler, more idiomatic solution. Original answer below the line.

---

As promised (though Brian already gave a very good answer), here's mine. Let's first get a few rules out there:

- A Task created with `task { ... }` will always be hot-started. That means it runs immediately on the current thread (or background thread if you use `backgroundTask`).
- A Task created through the TPL with the `Task<_>` classes will always be delay-started. Just like an `async` you will have to start these by hand.
- Binding any task in a `task` CE will start that task.
- The next binding expression will only start after the previous one is finished.

This means that, given an array or sequence with `Task`s, most likely they're already running by the time you get them. And since they weren't created through `bind`, they will run asynchronously. To prevent this, we need a few rules.

EDIT: check out [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) if you haven't already, it can do the below things out of the box.

### Rule 0: When dealing with tasks, always return a `task`

When combining tasks, binding tasks or joining them, always return the result as a `task`. This will simplify your overall flow, besides, you cannot return a non-task (or non-async) without blocking the thread.

### Rule 1: delay your tasks

Brian suggests to do this through `lazy`. This is fine. You can also simply use unit-functions: `fun() -> task { dosomething }`.

### Rule 2: don't use `.Result` or `.Wait()`

These will block your thread.

### Rule 3: don't use things like `List.traverseTaskResultA`

These functions, part of the otherwise excellent [`FsToolkit.ErrorHandling.TaskResult`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling.TaskResult/) library, will not execute your tasks as `run X -> wait for result -> run Y -> wait for result`. Instead, they do `run X -> run Y -> run Z -> asTask`.

In other words, those library functions will lead to asynchronous, overlapping execution.

### Rule 4: don't use `Thread.Sleep`

Hardly a rule, but while I was testing your scenario, I used `Thread.Sleep`. The problem is, this function blocks the current thread. It will give the false impression that your functions are running in sequence in your test scenario, but then in your real-world scenario they don't anymore.

Use `Task.Delay` instead. It works the same, but won't block the thread.

### Solution

There are multiple ways to do this. I will just present you a single one using `ContinueWith`. Steps:

- Your tasks must be returned delayed, as unit functions
- Your tasks don't rely on each other's result (this can easily be changed, though)
- Wrap your tasks in a continuation, and then `Unwrap` that continuation again.

This last one seems a little odd, but the TPL doesn't come with a standard `bind`. And the `bind` from F#, though applicable here, is a little hard to use. The `Ply` lib comes with an easier bind, you may try that out as well.

Anyway, here's the hardcore way, using only standard library functions. The good news is, you only have to write this function once.

```
/// Join multiple delayed tasks and return the result of the last
let join tasks =
    let wrapNext (t: unit -> Task<_>) (source: unit -> Task<_>): unit -> Task<_> =
        fun () ->
            source()
                // this is the CORE of the whole operation
                .ContinueWith((fun (_: Task) -> t ()), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
                // extra step needed, as BCL has no direct way to unwrap nested tasks
                .Unwrap() :?> Task<_>

    let rec combine acc (tasks: (unit -> Task<_>) list) =
        match tasks with
        | [] -> acc
        | t :: tail -> combine (wrapNext t acc) tail

    match tasks with
    | first :: rest -> combine first rest
    | [] -> failwith "oh oh, no tasks given!"
```

Here's how you can use it. The first function looks a little hacky, but it's just to mimic your scenario and to be able to double-check that it runs sequentially.

```
/// Create 10 tasks, use stream for writing, otherwise would garble FSI
/// Note that those can be task or backgroundTask
let createBunchOfTasks(sw: StreamWriter) =
    let mutable x = 0
    let rnd () = Random().Next(10, 30)
    let o = obj ()

    let runTask i = backgroundTask {
        let! _ = Task.Delay(rnd ())  // use randomization to ensure tasks last different times
        x <- x + 1

        // just some logging to a file, stdout is not good in this case
        lock o (fun () -> sw.WriteLine(sprintf "Task #%i after delay: %i" i x))
        return x
    }

    [
        // creating bunch of dummy tasks
        for i in 0..10 do
            fun () -> runTask i
    ]
```

In your scenario, you won't need the above code, but you will need something like this to call the `join` function. If you need logging to a file, you can use this pattern, but it was really only here for my sanity check, and is rather crude ;).

```
let runMultipleTasks() =
    // should give this as argument, as must be closed after all tasks completed
    let file = File.Open("output1.txt", FileMode.Create)
    let stream = new StreamWriter(file)

    // the actual creation of tasks 
    let tasks = createBunchOfTasks stream
    let combinedTask = join tasks

    // start the combined tasks
    combinedTask()
```

### Simpler, more idiomatic solution

After tinkering a little bit more about lists, sequences or arrays of tasks, the main issue is that they must be delayed. It turns out that you can do that with `task` itself, using `for`.

However, you have to be careful not to just use `yield`, but to use `let!` in combination with `yield`. This will ensure the tasks will be sequentially awaited:

```
let runMultipleTasks() = task {
    // should give this as argument, as must be closed after all tasks completed
    let file = File.Open("output1.txt", FileMode.Create)
    let stream = new StreamWriter(file)

    // the actual creation of tasks 
    let tasks = createBunchOfTasks stream |> Array.ofList
    let len = Array.length tasks
    let results = Array.zeroCreate len

    for i in 0..len - 1 do
        let! result = tasks[i]()  // ensure await-on-next
        results[i] <- result

    return List.ofArray results
}
```

Note: the library [`IcedTasks`](https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/IcedTasks/) has a `ColdTask` type which allows the above in a much simpler way, as if it is a normal task, and ensure cold-starting.

Comment: You may also check out these async antipatterns, some of the "rules" above are there too: https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use laziness to prevent the tasks from starting too soon. For example:

```ml
let createTask n =
    task {
        printfn $"Task {n} started"
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        printfn $"Task {n} finished"
        return 100 + n
    }

let lazyTasks =
    seq {
        for n = 1 to 10 do
            lazy createTask n
    }
```

So in your case, you would write:

```ml
for cardTransactionWithOrder in cardTransactionswithOrder do
    let lazyMatchedTransaction = lazy matchTransaction(page,bnzBatch,cardTransactionWithOrder, xeroClient)
    yield lazyMatchedTransaction
```

You can then evaluate any sequence of lazy tasks sequentially like this:

```ml
let evalTasksSequential lazyTasks =
    task {
        return seq {
            for (lazyTask : Lazy<Task<_>>) in lazyTasks do
                yield lazyTask.Value.Result   // start task and wait for it to finish
        }
    }
```

Test example:

```ml
task {
    let! results = evalTasksSequential lazyTasks
    for result in results do
        printfn $"{result}"
} |> ignore
```

Output:

```
Task 1 started
Task 1 finished
101
Task 2 started
Task 2 finished
102
Task 3 started
Task 3 finished
103
Task 4 started
Task 4 finished
104
Task 5 started
Task 5 finished
105
Task 6 started
Task 6 finished
106
Task 7 started
Task 7 finished
107
Task 8 started
Task 8 finished
108
Task 9 started
Task 9 finished
109
Task 10 started
Task 10 finished
110
```

Comment: You may not want to use `Thread.Sleep` here. It'll block the thread, it won't even be able to asynchronously use that time to do something else. You can see this in FSI, where it blocks input. Instead, use `Task.Delay`, which is non-blocking. Same is true for using `.Result`, which will also be blocking afaict.

Comment: Good point. It was just some quick and dirty code to create a long-running task. Don't this in production code, kids! :)

Comment: I don't see the need for `lazy` here, as `seq` is already lazy, so task creation will be deferred to the execution of the `seq` workflow.

In the end it depends on how the `seq<Task<_>` is created, but if it's created this way ,with a seq workflow, you don't need to add lazy.

Comment: @Gus, I was just experimenting with Brian's code as well, it's non-trivial to make it non-blocking, even without `lazy`. The problem is the call to `.Result`, which will wait for the task to finish. That's not what you'd want here. Instead, you'd want to return a new task, that awaits all tasks in the list. Hence my choice to show the barebones approach with `ContinueWith`, which returns a `task`.

Answer (score 0):

```ml
cardTransactionswithOrders
|> List.map (fun cardTransactionWithOrder ->
  matchTransaction(page,bnzBatch,cardTransactionWithOrder, xeroClient) 
  |> Async.AwaitTask
  |> Async.RunSynchronously)
```